# Category And Subcategory url

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes

Hi Developers,
            i want url like www.xyz.com/category/subcateogry/subsubgcatogory its work in category but when i add category/subcategory it shows error 500. what is the solution.

This is my homecontroller

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->q;
        $brand_id = $request->brand_id;
        $sort_by = $request->sort_by;
        $category_id = (Category::where('name', $request->category_name)->first() != null) ? Category::where('name', $request->category_name)->first()->id : null;
        $subcategory_id = (SubCategory::where('name', $request->subcategory_name)->first() != null) ? SubCategory::where('name', $request->subcategory_name)->first()->id : null;
        $subsubcategory_id = (SubSubCategory::where('name', $request->subsubcategory_name)->first() != null) ? SubSubCategory::where('name', $request->subsubcategory_name)->first()->id : null;        $min_price = $request->min_price;
        $max_price = $request->max_price;
        $seller_id = $request->seller_id;

        $conditions = ['published' => 1];

        if($brand_id != null){
            $conditions = array_merge($conditions, ['brand_id' => $request->brand_id]);
        }
        if($category_id != null){
            $conditions = array_merge($conditions, ['category_id' => $category_id]);
        }
        if($subcategory_id != null){
            $conditions = array_merge($conditions, ['subcategory_id' => $subcategory_id]);
        }
        if($subsubcategory_id != null){
            $conditions = array_merge($conditions, ['subsubcategory_id' => $subsubcategory_id]);
        }
        if($seller_id != null){
            $conditions = array_merge($conditions, ['user_id' => Seller::findOrFail($seller_id)->user->id]);
        }

        $products = Product::where($conditions);

        if($min_price != null && $max_price != null){
            $products = $products->where('unit_price', '>=', $min_price)->where('unit_price', '<=', $max_price);
        }

        if($query != null){
            $searchController = new SearchController;
            $searchController->store($request);
            $products = $products->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
        }

        if($sort_by != null){
            switch ($sort_by) {
                case '1':
                    $products->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                    break;
                case '2':
                    $products->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
                    break;
                case '3':
                    $products->orderBy('unit_price', 'asc');
                    break;
                case '4':
                    $products->orderBy('unit_price', 'desc');
                    break;
                default:
                    // code...
                    break;
            }
        }

        $products = filter_products($products)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->paginate(12)->appends(request()->query());

        return view('frontend.product_listing', compact('products', 'query', 'category_id', 'subcategory_id', 'subsubcategory_id', 'brand_id', 'sort_by', 'seller_id','min_price', 'max_price'));
    }
```

its my route. In category its work fine but when i add category/subcategory it shows error 500

```
Route::get('/{category_name}', 'HomeController@search')->name('products.category');
Route::get('/{category_name}/{subcategory_name}', 'HomeController@search')->name('products.subcategory');
Route::get('/{category_name}/{subcategory_name}/{subsubcategory_name}', 'HomeController@search')->name('products.subsubcategory');
```

My View

```
<div class="breadcrumb-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="{{ route('home') }}">{{__('Home')}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ route('products') }}">{{__('All Categories')}}</a></li>
                    @if(isset($category_id))
                        <li class="active"><a href="{{ route('products.category', $category_id) }}">{{ \App\Category::find($category_id)->name }}</a></li>
                    @endif
                    @if(isset($subcategory_id))
                        <li ><a href="{{ route('products.category', \App\SubCategory::find($subcategory_id)->category->id) }}">{{ \App\SubCategory::find($subcategory_id)->category->name }}</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="{{ route('products.subcategory', $subcategory_id) }}">{{ \App\SubCategory::find($subcategory_id)->name }}</a></li>
                    @endif
                    @if(isset($subsubcategory_id))
                        <li ><a href="{{ route('products.category', \App\SubSubCategory::find($subsubcategory_id)->subcategory->category->id) }}">{{ \App\SubSubCategory::find($subsubcategory_id)->subcategory->category->name }}</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="{{ route('products.subcategory', \App\SubsubCategory::find($subsubcategory_id)->subcategory->id) }}">{{ \App\SubsubCategory::find($subsubcategory_id)->subcategory->name }}</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="{{ route('products.subsubcategory', $subsubcategory_id) }}">{{ \App\SubSubCategory::find($subsubcategory_id)->name }}</a></li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: error 500 what? which is the error?

Comment: when i add /abc/{subcategory_name} its work fine but when i add /{category_name}/{subcategory_name} then it shows

Answer (score 0):

Because in the `search` declaration there is no `subcategory_name` and no `subsubcategory_name` and Laravel is trying to assign those values to the method parameters with that name, so you have to add those as parameters:

```
public function search(Request $request, $category_name = null, $subcategory_name = null, $subsubcategory_name = null){...}
```

And Laravel will assign to those parameters the value that has the URL in the parts you have declared the variables in the routes.

Also, just as tips, have a look to [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: and nothing more? please chech the .env if you have the APP_DEBUG to true and then clear the cache "php artisan clear:cache" and then let me know if something is changed

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: products.subcategory] [URI: {category_name}/{subcategory_name}]

Comment: post the view where there is the form please (or at least the form)

Comment: One more thing, You are Available

Comment: @ShahzaibGirach `route('products.subcategory', $subcategory_id)` expect 2 parameter, the category id and the subcategory id (same thing for subsubcategory that expects 3 id), so instead you have to do `route('products.subcategory', $category_id, $subcategory_id)` for example

Comment: this route does not  required 2 parameter, because it is fetching data from Model,i think that Blade should get data from controller, Kindly guide me how to get data from controller to blade considering  i m using laravel.

Comment: `Route::get('/{category_name}/{subcategory_name}', 'HomeController@search')->name('products.subcategory');` requires two parameter, `category_name` and `subcategory_name`, so when you call `route(''products.subcategory'')` you have also to pass to the route the two parameter, in the order you want to be inserted, so the first parameter is the "category_name" in the route and the secondo is the "subcategory_name" in the route, and so the method call should be something like  `route('products.subcategory', $category->name, $subcategory->name)` or something like this

Comment: I change my controller now i m passing data from controller

Comment: $cat_data = DB::table('categories')->where('id', $category_id)->first();
    $sub_cat_detail = DB::table('sub_categories')->where('id', $subcategory_id)->first();
    $sub_sub_cat_detail = DB::table('sub_sub_categories')->where('id', $subsubcategory_id)->first();
    $catArray = array(
        'cat_detail' => $cat_data,
        'sub_cat_detail' => $sub_cat_detail,
        'sub_sub_cat_detail' => $sub_sub_cat_detail,
    );

Comment: But i dont know how to pass this in href

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560680/laravel-associative-array-in-blade-url

Comment: kindly write some code of <a href="{{route(....)}}"> according to my code